# How did I get 15 points for an answer when there is not even one up vote?

Tags: discussion, support

I answered this [Install JDK 8 on Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326377/install-jdk-8-on-debian/350551#350551) and answer was chosen was by the OP. What I don't understand is how I won 15 points. Usually you win 2 points if somebody accepts your answer right ?

Maybe a glitch or some other forces at work which I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You get 2 points for accepting an answer to your question -- the person who wrote the answer gets 15. So in this case [user567](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/220614/user567?tab=reputation) is the one who got +2:

[image: +2 4 hours ago accept Install JDK 8 on Debian]

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation.